# Does akamai caches everything on a host or I must use headers to tell which to cache?

Tags: akamai

I am new to Akamai, thus my question is very basic.

How does Akamai decides what to cache? Does it caches everythin on a host it is enabled on or I have to tell explicitly using Pragma headers what to cache?

Another question if you don't mind! :) If I don't want to cache a response, is it necessary to set `Pragma: no-store` or I can simply not set any Pragma header at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it.
It's possible to:

- have custom rules in the CDN depending on specific rules such as matching url, cookies,...
- tell the CDN to honor your Cache-Control header
- or to add a proprietary header in your response

In each case you can choose whether you want to cache or not the response and how long.